# typeahead not working after textbox dynamic input

Tags: javascript, dynamic, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead

I use twitter bootstrap 3 typeahead, with bloodhound suggestion engine.

I have applied this typeahead in a textbox(class:typeahead) inside html table's column, and after selecting the typeahead, a new row appear.

I have a problem to apply the typeahead to this newly dynamically added textbox(also class:typeahead). Chrome dev error: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

This is my JS:

```
<script src="<?php echo site_url('assets/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js');?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo site_url('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js');?>"></script>

<script src="<?php echo site_url('assets/js/bloodhound.js');?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo site_url('assets/js/typeahead.jquery.js');?>"></script>

<script>

/*///////////////////
// bloodhound
//
*/
var stocksData = source_inventory;
var stocks = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (d) { 
        for (var prop in d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.item_code);}        
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    //local:  ["(A)labama","Alaska","Arizona","Arkansas","Arkansas2","Barkansas"]
    limit: 5, //#2 added
    local : stocksData
});
stocks.initialize();

/*///////////////////
// typeahead
//
*/
function apply_typeahead(elm){ alert('tes and yes');
    $(elm).typeahead(null,{ 
        displayKey: function(stocks) {
            for (var prop in stocks) { 
                return stocks.item_code;
            }
        },
        source:stocks.ttAdapter() ,
        updater: function (stocks) {
            return stocks;
        }
    }).on('typeahead:selected', function (obj, datum) {
        var var_datum = [];
        var_datum[0] = datum.item_id;
        dialog_inventory_pull_data(var_datum);
    });
}

//apply_typeahead('input[name^=ast_code].typeahead');



$(document).ready(function(){
    /*
        //some code
    */
});


/*$('.typeahead').on('added',function(){
    apply_typeahead('input[name^=ast_code].typeahead');
    //$('.typeahead').typeahead(typeaheadSettings);
});*/

//JS CUSTOM PAGE

function table_detail_insert(data){     
    if(data){       
        for(var p = 0;p<data.length;p++){
            /*code*/            
        }
        //apply_typeahead($('input[name^=ast_code].typeahead'));
        //apply_typeahead('input[name^=ast_code].typeahead');
        return data;        
    }else{
        console.log('error');   
    }   
}
var url_1 = "/inventory/detail";
function dialog_inventory_pull_data(data_inventory){ 
    var data_inventory_param = $.map(data_inventory, function(value, index) {
        return [value];
    });
    var data_ajax_raw = $.ajax({
        url:ajax_url_1,
        data: {inventory:data_inventory_param},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result){
            table_detail_insert(result);            
        }
    }); 
}   

</script>
```

i tried to run the apply_typeahead function from console, it works with the initialized textbox, but after new row dynamically created, running again the same function from console is not working and all textbox have no typeahead.

what could possibly wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is for the dynamically added input elements, you need to initialize the plugin after they are created.

So one solution is first create a method which can be reused to initialize the plugin for a passed set of elements like

Link: [Working on dynamically added input elements with Typeahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28445829/working-on-dynamically-added-input-elements-with-typeahead)